# How to use wild card in ant fileset or src

Tags: java, ant

Using ant 1.5
I am trying to create a jar file with files compiled under product directory that can constantly change the build name

```
/target
   |---myapp-1.3.5-SNAPSHOT
          |--- WEB-INF
                 |---classes
                 |---i18n
```

It's kind of picky but I have to make a jar file that still keep the `web` structure

```
|---myapp-utility.jar
       |--- WEB-INF
              |---classes
              |---i18n
```

That means I have to put wild card to identify the directory with build and snapshot

```
<jar destfile="myapp-utility.jar">
    <manifest>
        ....
    </manifest>
    <fileset dir="myapp-**/"/>
</jar>
```

and it doesn't work, wild card is not recognized. So what is the alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pathconvert](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) to analyze the wildcard specification:

```xml
<pathconvert property="myapp.dir">
    <dirset dir="target" includes="myapp-*"/>
</pathconvert>

<jar destfile="myapp-utility.jar">
    <manifest>
        <!-- .... -->
    </manifest>
    <fileset dir="${myapp.dir}"/>
</jar>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ant 1.5 is a very old version of Ant. If you can use at least Ant 1.8.2 (released in 2010), you can use the following...

```
<jar destfile="myapp-utility.jar">
    <mappedresources>
        <fileset dir="target">
            <include name="myapp-*/**"/>
        </fileset>
        <cutdirsmapper dirs="1"/>
    </mappedresources>
</jar>
```

The [`<mappedresources>` resource collection](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#mappedresources) wraps the `<fileset>` element and then applies a [mapper](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html) to the results.

It's true that the `dir` of `<fileset>` can't handle wildcards. Luckily, `<include>` can handle wildcards. So, the above puts the wildcard test into `<include>`. The `**` ensures all files under `myapp-*` are matched.

Finally, [`<cutdirsmapper>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html#cutdirs-mapper) removes the `myapp-1.3.5-SNAPSHOT/` part from each file.